# How to get live, non-blocking output from process

Tags: c++, linux, command-line-interface, ipc

I want to be able to capture the output of a cli program (before it terminates) for which I don't have the source code.

Everything I have found was either done with pipes, which to my understanding only send the output on a flush or on exit of the program.
One solution I have found on [Codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16163/Real-Time-Console-Output-Redirection) is only for Windows.

Comment: You need to use a pseudo-tty to make the program unbuffer its output. You can use the `unbuffer` program that comes with `Expect` to do this.

Comment: So you can use `popen("unbuffer cli_program", "r")`

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stdbuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html) to force `stdout` and `stderr` of an application to be line-buffered, even when redirected into a pipe or a file:

```
stdbuf --output=L --error=L <program> | ...
```